# Merge CSV files in different folders using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have about 5600 directories structured as follows:

[image: structure of dirs]

I need to merge all A files into one file, all B files into another file, and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you need all "root directory/dir1" csv files into a single df? Also do they have the exact same structure?

Comment: I need to merge all the A files into one file, all the B files into one file, etc.... Basically, I need to output 7 files: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and each X file contains within it the union of the X files contained in the 5600 dirs.
All the files have the same header

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this should work for your case (I used a `RootDir` with 2 subdirectories `Dir1` and `Dir2` with in each 2 files `A.csv` and `B.csv`). You can change the value of `rootdir` to match your usecase:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
rootdir = 'RootDir' # Change when needed to your root directory
files = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(rootdir) for f in filenames if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.csv']
names = set([x.rstrip('.csv').split('/')[-1] for x in files])
df_dict = {key: pd.DataFrame() for key in names}
for file in files:
    key = file.rstrip('.csv').split('/')[-1]
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_dict[key] = pd.concat([df_dict[key], df])
```

Output is a dictionary of dataframes `df_dict` with `A` and `B` as keys.

Use `df_dict['A']` to access DataFrame `A` and so on...